# How do i get the mouse coordinates X and Y in form1 mouse enter event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

`e` doesn't have the properties `X` and `Y`.

I want when the mouse cursor move over a control it will do something.

Comment: Share your code what you have tried

Comment: Take a look at [OnMouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousemove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Aniket The OP _has_ shown the current code - there's no X and Y property on `EventArgs` to show anything more meaningful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the current cursor position using the `Cursor.Current` static property:

```
var x = Cursor.Current.Position.X;
var y = Cursor.Current.Position.Y;
```

Note that the `MouseEnter` event only fires when the cursor *enters* the control boundary.  That may be what you want, but your last sentence seems to indicate you want to know when the mouse moves *within* a control.  In that case, `MouseMove` may be a more appropriate event to handle.

Comment: This syntax doesn't work for me.  `Cursor.Position` works, but `Cursor.Current.Position` results in `Member 'System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`.  Am I the only one?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Control.MousePosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static property as follows:

```
void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Point screenPosition = MousePosition; 
    Point clientPosition = PointToClient(screenPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = e.Location;
    }
```